# how to auto update an SQL database table with entities from Power BI Dataflow?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-sql-database, dataflow, powerbi-datasource

Is there a step process to automatically update an Azure sql table from an existing Power BI dataflow with entities created from a different data source. In other word, Using power BI dataflows as an ETL tool, with updates from one Azure sql table to another. Feedback appreciated on a step process to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with data flows. They are only an ETL tool to READ from a source then connect Power BI to them. You cannot use them to read database table, then output it back to another database table. You will need something like Azure Data Factory to move and or orchestrate data movement and stored procedures execution in a database.